# 2D array to Double Link List Or Custom data structure in c# for grid purspose?

Tags: c#, data-structures, grid

Ok, so I have a 2D array of objects that are represented in a 2D space with columns and raws translated into (x,y) points (Cartesian coordinate system).

The problem began when I wanted to get access from one object to their neighbours.

I immediately thought that I can get access to them by looking i,j from an iteration into the 2D array like this:

```
         (i,j+1)
            ↑
(i-1,j) ← (i,j) → (i+1,j)
            ↓
         (i,j-1)
```

Everything was fine until my grid changed shape into a non-rectangle shape.

Then a java guy told me that I should use a custom data structure to hold the references of my objects that is literally a Double Link List with not only next and previous pointers but instead with top , down, right and left pointers. That I shouldn't write code like this for a regular array, and to use a proper data structure that is going to give me more power and flexibility on how to insert, delete, initialize and many other functions for my objects.

For some reason, I thought he is right.

In this way, I think that I can create more complex functions like getting all objects in a radius from one point. This is for game dev purposes and latter on algorithms like A* for pathfinding are going to be developed and run on this structure.

So my question is:
Is any build-in structure in c# that can help me with this or if not, should I try to create one custom structure from scratch or try to extend-inherit an already build-in c# structure. 
What is the proper terminology for that structure? Maxtrix Link List? Multiway Link List?

P.S. I avoided posting code because it's from a custom game engine that needs a lot of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea...

I would develop a class (i.e. `Space`) holding a simple list of another custom class (i.e. `Point`).
The master class could have some properties defining space shape and extension, and can implement a series of question method (`Point GetNearest(Point p)`, `List<Point> GetPointsInRadius(int center, int radius)`, ...) each of them iterating throw the list of points, and a set of add/delete/move Points methods

Your `Point` class have a list of  properties( `int x, int y, Point top, Point down, Point left, Point right`) and a series of method (`int DistanceFrom(Point p), bool IncludedIn(int center, int radius), int DistanceFromLeft/Right/Top/Down()`, ... and so on

Comment: That doesn't sound like a bad idea, to be honest. So, the point class is the node class and the Space class is the Data Structured class. This method constructed a custom data Structured as I understand.